# Remove noise from a binary image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to get an image only with the grapes and the three circles (red, green, blue).
[I need to remove all the smears].
how can I improve my code for that?

this is my code:

```
RGB = imread('img_3235.jpg');
GRAY = rgb2gray(RGB);

threshold = graythresh(GRAY);
originalImage = im2bw(GRAY, threshold);

originalImage = bwareaopen(originalImage,250);

imshow(originalImage);

CC = bwconncomp(originalImage); %Ibw is my binary image
stats = regionprops(CC,'pixellist');
```

this is my image (img_3235.jpg).
[image]

and this is the result of my code:
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can perform a morpholical closing using [`IMCLOSE`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imclose.html).

```
se = strel('disk', 10); %# structuring element
closeBW = imclose(originalImage,se);
figure, imshow(closeBW);
```

The [closing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology#Closing) of A by B is obtained by the dilation of A by B, followed by erosion of the resulting structure by B.

[image: Result]

Comment: it works! thank you!
I am updating my topic with another problem :/ thank you!

Answer (score 7):

An alternative solution is to median filter with an appropriate window size, just after the threshold is applied:

```
 ...
 originalImage = im2bw(GRAY, threshold);
 originalImage = medfilt2(originalImage,[37 37],'symmetric'); 
 originalImage = bwareaopen(originalImage,250);
 figure, imshow(originalImage);
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! I will check which option is more essential for me. thank you very much!! :]]